# PhotoEditorSDK Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'export' of null

Tags: photoeditorsdk

Currently using photoeditorsdk@4.3.1

With pure JS example, export image works just fine.

```
window.onload = () => {

  const container = document.getElementById('app')

  const editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
    container,
    license: JSON.stringify(PESDK_LICENSE),
    assets: {
      baseUrl:'/assets'
    },
  })

  window.editor = editor
}
```

When try to wrap photoeditorsdk into a React Component as following

```
class Editor extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    const container = this.refs.pesdk
    const editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
      container,
      license: JSON.stringify(PESDK_LICENSE),
      assets: {
        baseUrl: '/assets'
      },
      title: 'Photo Editor'
    })

    window.editor = editor
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div ref='pesdk'></div>
    )
  }
}

export default Editor
```

and export image using

```
editor.export(false).then(image => document.body.append(image))
```

from `window.editor` will encounter the errror

```
react-dom.development.js:5622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'export' of null
    at t.export (react-dom.development.js:5622)
    at <anonymous>:1:14
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this here. Can you give more details? E.g., where and when are you calling `editor.export` from. Also, are you passing an image to the editor as an option?